# Package name not found for an android app in 'Internal testing' in playstore

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, integration-testing

A flutter app is moved to 'Internal testing' status in playstore. Then I try to enable facebook login for the app. In https://developers.facebook.com/apps/944236743529578/fb-login/quickstart/ portal I try to mention package name..But I get error as invalid package name.. May I know how to overcome this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgy6c.png)

I built the app with a package name and moved to Internal testing status in google playstore. I expected the package name recognisable in Facebook developer portal... but it is not recognisable..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

is there a typo in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for the package name? The string has to match exactly. Also check how you entered it in the Facebook Developer portal.

Could also be propagation. After moving your app to "Internal testing" status on the Google Play Store, it may take some time for the package name to be recognized.

Comment: Hi .. there is no typo error... I checked it again.. it has been more than 24 hours since the app has been uploaded to playstore..

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is not possible to integrate facebook login unless it is published in the play store.. Please go through this link.. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/261648152949557